# Chrome gives error This site can’t be reached for https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php but actually the page exists

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome gives error This site can’t be reached for https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php but actually the page exists

checked with firefox, safari- but the page breaks here.

What is the problem with Chrome browser

Chrome:49.0.26 (Older version)

Comment: The problem is likely an obsolete version. Web browsers should be kept up to date, always!

Comment: Do you mean that all browsers fail on this website? Is at least one of the browsers up to date and if so, what error message does it give?

Comment: @harrymc its only on chrome 49.0, not all on all browsers. I am curious to know why is the error : This site can't be reached

Comment: Probably lack of support for some new feature.